# Crashing while serializing Core data model

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, alamofire

I'm new to `CoreData` and I'm stuck in serializing the `CoreData` model.

I need to sync an entire object's save in code to an API. I'm able to save the context and fetch the result. The problem is in the function where I call the API to synchronize.

Here is my code:

```
var theJSONText = ""
dataToSend["trigger"] = ""
dataToSend["gcm"] = ""
dataToSend["client"] = "ios"
dataToSend["deviceId"] = 
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
dataToSend["deviceName"] = UIDevice.current.name
dataToSend["login_source"] = loginSource
dataToSend["lastsync"] = 0
dataToSend["rows"] = []
dataToSend["urlencode"] = true
if let rows = rows {
    for row in rows {
        if row.syncRequired == 1 {
            rowsToSync.append(row)
        }
    }
}
rowsToSync.resultType = NSDictionary
dataToSend["rows"] = rowsToSync
print( dataToSend["rows"])
if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
    withJSONObject: dataToSend,
    options: []) {
    theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                     encoding: .ascii)!
    print("JSON string = \(theJSONText)")
}
params["data"] = theJSONText
APIService.shared.syncUser(params: params) { (success, data, error) in
    if success {
        print("success in global sync")
        rows = data?.rows
    } else {
        print("failure in global sync")
        print(error?.errorMessage)
    }
}
```

Here, `rows` is an array containing all objects. This is saved in `CoreData`.

The API works fine when I pass nothing in `rows`, but when it contains the objects, the code crashes at the line `:

```
try? JSONSerialization.data(
    withJSONObject: dataToSend
```

error on console:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Rows)'
```

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: @Larme , This is the error printed in console:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Rows)'

Comment: What it `rowToSync`, what's in it. I guess it has `Rows` objects that aren't JSON. You need to transform them.

Comment: @Larme so that means if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
    withJSONObject: dataToSend,
    options: []) {
    theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                     encoding: .ascii)!

this will not transform "Rows" object to Json?

Comment: In JSON, you can only have (NS)Dictionary, (NS)Array, (NS)String and (NS)Numbers (in Swift including `Int`, `Float`, etc.) and null (but that's a special case) cf the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization?language=objc . `Rows` is a class that doesn't respect that. It's a custom one. You need to "translator" to transform a `Rows` object into one that's compliant.